# How can I open a modal from a navbar with react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

Currently, I have a `nav`

```
  <Nav pullRight className="navright">
    <NavItem href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? '' : 'hidden'}>{this.state.name}</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? 'hidden' : ''}>Login</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? 'hidden' : ''}>Sign Up</NavItem>
  </Nav>
```

I don't know what `eventKey` is or if it's needed. But I want to open up my modal (called `AuthModal`) when either of those are clicked. I want to open `AuthModal` passing an attribute of either `'login'` or `'signup'`

How can this be done? I'm using `redux` if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code eventKey is only for the alert. So you alert the number pass ;)

```
function handleSelect(selectedKey) {
  alert('selected ' + selectedKey);
}

const navInstance = (
  <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={1} onSelect={handleSelect}>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">NavItem 2 content</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
  </Nav>
);
```

If you want to open modal look at the modal code.

```
getInitialState() { // This is the old way but can work
    return { showModal: false };
  },

constructor() { // New way
  super();
  this.state = {
    showModal: false
  }
}   



  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  },

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  },
```

---

And your modal need this code `<Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>`

So here you just need to call the open function and the close for close it. All working by the state of react.

If you use redux you can make a reducer who see if the toggleModal is false. And with a action you can dispatch it to true.

This is a version for your own problem

```
class NavInstance extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    }
  }

  handleToggleModal() {
    this.setState(
      showModal: !this.state.showModal
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav bsStyle="pills">
          <NavItem href="/home">NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
          <NavItem title="Item">NavItem 2 content</NavItem>
          <NavItem disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
          <NavItem onClick={() => this.handleToggleModal()}>Show Modal</NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <MyModal show={this.state.showModal} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MyModal = ({ show }) => 
  <Modal show>
    My Modal
  </Modal>
```

Hope that can help

Comment: The modal is a different component. This is the `Navbar` component

Comment: is there the equivalent of a `ng-click` that I can put on the `NavItem`?

Comment: You can do same what you do is call the modal by the click on the navbar.

Comment: Yes you can `onClick={() => this.open()}`

Comment: But it's not `this`, is it? Sorry, I'm a bit confused. `this` is the `MyNavbar` component. and `open` would be in the `AuthModal` component?

Comment: In react you make the action in the component. If the action is inside you can by this. Don't forget to `.bind(this)` but that's why I do `() => ` so I bind this.

So you need to have your modal inside the component navbar you can just call it no need to have it completely. 

When you click the navbar link you open the modal ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124930/discussion-between-shamoon-and-emanuel-quimper).

Comment: I'm in the chat